# Website keeps loading

Tags: apache, vagrant, nfs, vagrantfile

**Setup**

- Vagrant Box (Ubuntu 12.04 / `nfs mount`, for performance purposes).
- Apache Version Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- CakePHP 3 Project.

**Vhost**

Took from [here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fd1rk%2F588511&ei=wJUtVYOiGMXN7QbDhoH4DQ&usg=AFQjCNGDzSWKNvw8E_93MvmS_p1f9S4E0w&sig2=3iUOPR_NPNEGUwBS1HyBNQ&bvm=bv.90790515,d.ZGU).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.kitchen.com
   ServerAlias www.kitchen.com kitchen.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/kitchen/webroot

   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.kitchen.com-access.log combined
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.kitchen.com-error.log

   Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

   #disable htaccess starting at /
   <Directory />
            AllowOverride none
    </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/kitchen/webroot/>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

            <Files sitemap.xml>
                    RewriteEngine Off
            </Files>
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All my .htaccess inside the project are the [default ones](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache)

**Part of the Vagrantfile**

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.20"
config.vm.synced_folder "./www", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
```

**/etc/hosts on the host machine**

```
192.168.33.20 www.kitchen.com kitchen.com
```

---

- I am able to reach an existing file (`www.kitchen.com/css/base.css` for example).
- **When I'm trying to load `www.kitchen.com` the site keeps loading overtime**.

---

I looked in the logs (syslog, access logs, error logs, ...) but nothing relevant ...
I also checked apache user and my project files permissions:

```
Apache User/Group:  www-data(33)/33

$ (/var/www/kitchen) ls -la
files:   -rw-r--r--  1 502 dialout
folders: drwxr-xr-x  9 502 dialout
```

Comment: You should have `Options FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride All` in your `<Directory></Directory>`

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: Even when you restart your server?

Comment: Ye. But i figured it out. I put the `Options FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride All` in the default vhost, and removed all the lines from the logs until the end.